# Firebase http trigger has an empty body?

Tags: express, httprequest, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to trigger a http request to my firebase cloud functions using the following code,

```
fetch( 'my-cloud-function-address', {
  method: 'POST',
    body: {
      id: token.id,
      email: token.email,
      amount: 2100,
      description: 'Full Deck'
    }
  })
  .then( res => {
    console.log( res )
  })
```

And in my cloud functions,

```
const
functions = require( 'firebase-functions' ),
admin     = require( 'firebase-admin' ),
cors      = require( 'cors' )({ origin: true })

admin.initializeApp( functions.config().firebase )

exports.chargeCard = functions.https.onRequest( ( req, res ) => {
console.log( req, req.body )
cors( req, res, () => {
    res.send( `Success!` )
  } )
} )
```

So... A few issues... Please bear with me if it's a really noob question as it's the first time I'm trying out http requests.

1. My req has a chunk of stuff, but my req.body is an empty object. And in the req, I can't find the information that I've sent in.
2. My res shows a chunk of stuff, but I can't find the "Success!" I've
   sent anywhere too.
3. So basically, the http request seems to have been successfully triggered on both ends it seems like a success, but I do not have any data passed to each other.